# How can I customise the Stripe payment using the Enupal craft plugin?

Tags: craftcms

Have followed the documentation
https://enupal.com/craft-plugins/stripe-payments/docs/plugin-development/template-overrides

Created a folder in my templates folder
templates/_stripe/donations/_frontend/[all the folders within frontend folder]

How can I include this in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add the next path under the `Templates Folder` input on your payment form:

`_stripe/donations/_frontend`

And don't forget to enable the `Custom templates` lightswitch

Then display your payment form as usual (it will take your template override folder)

```
{{ craft.enupalStripe.paymentForm('handle') }}
```